How to set Firefox Portable as default browser in Windows 11?
I'm trying to change my default browser in Windows 11 to Mozilla Firefox Portable Edition, which is installed at D:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe. Since it's a portable browser, it doesn't have an option to set itself as the system's default browser.
I've attempted to change this manually through Windows 11 Settings > Apps > Default Apps. I'm trying to modify the values assigned to HTTP and HTTPS, which are currently set to Chrome. However, I'm encountering an issue:
The only options available are Microsoft Edge, Chrome, or the Microsoft Store. There's no option to specify a custom path like D:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe.
How can I set Firefox Portable as my default browser for HTTP and HTTPS protocols in Windows 11?
Additional details:

OS: Windows 11
Browser: Mozilla Firefox Portable Edition
Installation path: D:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe

I've attached a screenshot of the Default Apps settings page to illustrate the issue.


Have you registered Firefox to Windows? See: https://superuser.com/a/1496750/403203

Technically speaking, you can't make a portable app, the default. As soon as you do this, the app is not portable anymore. If you go that route anyway, consider installing the normal version.
